# Appropriateness of log-rank test

Tags: survival, small-sample, logrank-test

I'm working on factors related to survival of a small size sample (26 patients) for a period of time, this sample was divided in 2 groups (16 vs 10 patients), the events were little (7 in total). I had multiple cases with expected values less than 5.
Please, is it appropriate to use the Log-rank test in this study? If it isn't, what can I use instead? Thank you!
Best regards

Comment: The issues are more to do with the seemingly pragmatic nature of the design. If you had a *randomized* sample, with a robust number of failures in either arm, a log-rank test would be a fine inferential approach. 7 events will certainly be underpowered - but we might be interested in the result regardless. If "expected values less than 5" refers to the failure times, then it shouldn't matter as the log-rank test is invariant to the actual time scale.

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful answer! "expected values less than 5": I meant some cells contain expected failure below 5.

Comment: That still doesn't mean anything - define precisely what you mean by "expected failure" - do you mean expected failure "time"? Or fewer than 5 expected failures? - and by expected, I think you mean *observed*. So there were 7 failures overall, and the distribution is 3/4 or something like that... is that correct?

Comment: I meant by "failure" the "event" that is death in my study. Thank you for your help!